# Java encrypting and decryption of image files using AES and a hashed password as key

Tags: java, security, encryption, cryptography, aes

I've looked at several posts on this topic, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26058823/correct-way-of-encrypting-and-decrypting-an-image-using-aes) post to actually encrypt/decrypt, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9536827/generate-key-from-string) post on generating a key using a string as a seed to generate a random key. The encryption reduces my filesize from 3mb to 16 bytes and the decryption reduces it further to 0 bytes. I also watched [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PCpKGvfN3bk&t=1s&ab_channel=ThamizharasaN) on the topic and my code had the same issues with the file size being reduced to zero in the decryption process, while his worked fine.

This is my function generating a key based on a SHA256 hash passed as `k`:

```
 public static Key keyGen(String k) throws Exception {
     SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
     KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(k.toCharArray(), k.getBytes(), 12, 128);
     SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
     return new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");
 }
```

These are the functions I'm using to encrypt and decrypt:

```
public static void encrypt(Key key, byte[] content) throws Exception {
        Cipher cipher;
        byte[] encrypted = null;
        try {
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,  key);
            encrypted = cipher.doFinal(content);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        saveFile(encrypted);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Encryption complete");
    }


 public static void decrypt(Key key, byte[] textCryp) throws Exception {
        Cipher cipher;
        byte[] decrypted = null;
        try {
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
            decrypted = cipher.doFinal(textCryp);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        saveFile(decrypted);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Decryption complete");
    }
```

The function I'm using to write the contents back into the file:

```
   public static void saveFile(byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("filepath/test.jpg");
        fos.write(bytes);
        fos.close();
    }
```

And finally, the function that gets the byte representation of the image file, passed into the encrypt/decrypt functions as "content":

```
public static byte[] getFile() {

    File f = new File("filepath/test.jpg");
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = new FileInputStream(f);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
    byte[] content = null;
    try {
        content = new byte[is.available()];
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        is.read(content);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return content;
}
```

And the main function calling these functions:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Key key = keyGen("1234567812345678");
    byte[] fileContents = getFile();
    //I change to decrypt after I call encrypt
    encrypt(key,fileContents);

 }
```

No errors or exceptions are thrown, and the posts and video I referenced while writing this code seems to be working fine.

I would really appreciate an advice on this as this is the final part of a project I've been working on for a long time.

Comment: Don't, ever, use available(). It doesn't do what you think it does. Use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllBytes-java.nio.file.Path- to read a file.

Comment: You don't show any of the code that calls these methods, so it's impossible to determine why you are getting the results you claim to be getting.

Comment: I added the main function calling them.

Comment: Despite your buggy `getFile()` method your code works for me.

Comment: @JBNizet Although correct, I can remember that `available` *generally* returns the right value for files. Maybe not for large media files, I'm not sure. So although good advice, there maybe something else wrong as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more trials, I realized the test file I was trying to run the code on was in a cloud drive. I copied the file to a local directory, reran the code and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Your code is still incorrect, in fact your `getFile()` method is like an anti-pattern demo.